# making objects clickable in ar.js

Tags: three.js, aframe, ar.js

box.setAttribute('cursor',{
rayOrigin: 'mouse'
});
box.addEventListener('click', e => {
alert("clicked");
});

in this code the click event is working only when object is at the center of the screen. I want to make it clickable at any part of the screen is there any way to do so??

Answer (score 0):

1. The event listener is on the component which is doing the ray casting. If you want the `box` to respond to the click, then move the cursor component to a different entity. I'd recommend putting just adding it to an entity in your scene.

```
<a-entity cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: .box"></a-entity>
```

2. Add the `class='box'` attribute to the box in question. There's more info in the [Raycaster docs](https://aframe.io/docs/1.1.0/components/raycaster.html#selecting-entities-to-test-for-intersection) explaining why.

Comment: let scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');
 let pit = document.createElement('a-box');
 
 pit.setAttribute('class', 'box');
 pit.setAttribute('position', "0 0 0");
 pit.setAttribute('rotation', '180 180 180');
 pit.setAttribute('look-at', '[gps-projected-camera]');
 pit.setAttribute('scale', '5 5 5');
 pit.setAttribute('cursor', {
  rayOrigin: 'mouse'
 });
 pit.setAttribute('raycaster', {
  objects: '.box'
 });
this my code still it is not working as expected the click function is only working in the centre of the screen